# System log full of session and slice messages

Tags: syslog

I have a new CentOS 7 installation, and noticed that my /var/log/messages file is full of messages like this

```
Mar  6 08:40:01 myhostname systemd: Started Session 2043 of user root.
Mar  6 08:40:01 myhostname systemd: Starting Session 2043 of user root.
Mar  6 08:40:01 myhostname systemd: Created slice user-1001.slice.
Mar  6 08:40:01 myhostname systemd: Starting user-1001.slice.
Mar  6 08:40:01 myhostname systemd: Started Session 2042 of user userx.
Mar  6 08:40:01 myhostname systemd: Starting Session 2042 of user userx.
Mar  6 08:40:01 myhostname systemd: Started Session 2041 of user root.
Mar  6 08:40:01 myhostname systemd: Starting Session 2041 of user root.
Mar  6 08:40:31 myhostname systemd: Removed slice user-1001.slice.
Mar  6 08:40:31 myhostname systemd: Stopping user-1001.slice.
Mar  6 08:41:01 myhostname systemd: Created slice user-1001.slice.
Mar  6 08:41:01 myhostname systemd: Starting user-1001.slice.
Mar  6 08:41:01 myhostname systemd: Started Session 2044 of user userx.
Mar  6 08:41:01 myhostname systemd: Starting Session 2044 of user userx.
Mar  6 08:41:21 myhostname systemd: Removed slice user-1001.slice.
Mar  6 08:41:21 myhostname systemd: Stopping user-1001.slice.
```

What do all of these mean, and why are they there?  If this is normal background noise them it seems like an enourmous waste to of resources to log this...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

(this question is also answered over on superuser [here](https://superuser.com/questions/919935/created-slice-user-0-slice-and-starting-session-2025-of-user-root-in-var) )

Those are messages pertaining to the creation and deletion of slices, which are used in systemd to group processes and manage their resources.

Why they are logged by default escapes me but I've seen two ways to disable them:

1. The less intrusive way is to filter them out by creating /etc/rsyslog.d/ignore-systemd-session-slice.conf with the following contents:

   ```
   if $programname == "systemd" and ($msg contains "Starting Session" or $msg contains "Started Session" or $msg contains "Created slice" or $msg contains "Starting user-" or $msg contains "Removed Slice" or $msg contains "Stopping user-") then stop
   ```

   and restart rsyslogd with `systemctl restart rsyslog`
2. The broader way is to set the systemd logging level a bit higher by editing `/etc/systemd/system.conf`:

   ```
    #LogLevel=info
    LogLevel=notice
   ```

References:

- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1564823
- I have more but can't post more than 2 links. Hooray.

Comment: Had to change if statement to `if $programname contains "systemd"` because program name is called `systemd-logind`

Comment: @Aidas, out of curiosity, what distro/systemd version?

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

Answer (score 3):

These messages are normal and expected -- they will be seen any time a user logs in

To suppress these log entries in /var/log/messages, create a discard filter with rsyslog, e.g., run the following command:

```
echo 'if $programname == "systemd" and ($msg contains "Starting Session" or $msg contains "Started Session" or $msg contains "Created slice" or $msg contains "Starting user-" or $msg contains "Starting User Slice of" or $msg contains "Removed session" or $msg contains "Removed slice User Slice of" or $msg contains "Stopping User Slice of") then stop' >/etc/rsyslog.d/ignore-systemd-session-slice.conf
```

Then restart the rsyslog service

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1564823

Comment: Are you sure they are shown when a user logs in? 
Monitoring `/var/log/messages` show this when `myuser` logs in:
`May 26 12:24:46 myhost systemd-logind: New session 40686 of user myuser.
May 26 12:24:46 myhost systemd: Started Session 40686 of user myuser.`, not the slice messages. I am interested in knowing the cause of **slice** messages.

Comment: @nephewtom slices are a systemd resource management term. In my case there's a cron job checking the system health, it creates these messages.