# How can I stop SSH server to send logs to syslog?

Tags: debian, sshd, rsyslog

Debian 10

I have a lot of log info like this:

```
localhost systemd[1]: Started Session 30522 of user xxxx.
```

How can I stop sshd to send logging info to sysconf ?

Thank you

---

I reproduced what [the suggested link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/267965/100397) provided but it did not work for me.
This is what I did:

I added a file in the /etc/rsyslog.d directory
In this file I put the following command:

```
if $programname == "systemd" and ($msg contains "Removed session" or $msg contains "New session" or $msg contains "session-" or $msg contains "Started Session") then stop
```

I relaunched `rsyslog`:

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

but I still have, for example, `Started Session 9999 of user foot` in syslog file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System log full of session and slice messages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267965/system-log-full-of-session-and-slice-messages)

Comment: (its not ssh server generating those log entrie, its systemd)

Answer (score 1):

It's not sshd generating those logs. These are low priority "info"-level messages related to session and resource management by systemd.

This can be prevented by typing the following in the shell:

```
$ systemd-analyze set-log-level notice
```

But you can also set the log level and/or filter the messages in `rsyslog`, for that see the following link: [System log full of session and slice messages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267965/system-log-full-of-session-and-slice-messages) (provided in comments by @afshin).